# Upgrade kentico from 9 to 10

Tags: upgrade, kentico

When i trying update kentico to 10 version i have a some problem:
"the selected folder is missing a vital kentico component"
but I'm sure I chose the right folder. Who mean why?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case, you only have the CMS folder from deployment. But the upgrade needs the Lib folder which was not needed for deployment. 
[image]

What you can do is to find the Lib folder from another instance or just install V9 of CMS, and you can find the missing Lib folder in C:\Program Files (x86)\Kentico\9.0\Webinstaller\Web

Comment: Thank you, I added the library to lib and its helped to solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if you are attempting to use the Kentico Hotfix Utility to upgrade from v9.0.50 to hotfix v10.0.41, which is not supported by Kentico. You cannot use the Kentico Hotfix Utility to upgrade Kentico from one major version to another. You need to:

1. First upgrade the project from 9.0.X => 10.0 - upgrade documentation available at https://docs.kentico.com/k10/installation/upgrading-to-kentico-10
2. Then you will need to run the project.
3. Then you can apply the latest hotfix utility - available at https://devnet.kentico.com/download/hotfixes
4. Then run the project again.

I appreciate you had a missing lib folder, but even if this were present, you still can't perform a major version upgrade using the hotfix utility.

Answer (score 0):

Few things can cause this:

- Customized core files
- Missing dll's
- Changes in the web.config which cause Kentico references to be broken
- and some other issues, but these are the most common we see.

Have you tried to open the project within Visual Studio and build the project?  Secondly, are you selecting the directory with the CMS and Lib directory in it?

Answer (score 0):

Does your project has the default structure or is it loke it was installed to the root of the web site? Default structure is some folder and underneath are the CMS, Lib and also the .sln file and few others. Looks like you have just the content of the CMS folder. In this case you either need the original project or upgrade the manual way.

Answer (score -1):

**You may also run CodeUpgrade tool from Kentico**

Basic detection

Run CodeUpgrade.exe from the command line, with the path to your project’s solution file as the parameter (WebSite.sln or WebApp.sln).

For example:

```
CodeUpgrade.exe C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Kentico9\WebSite.sln
```

**The tool generates a csv file containing a list of custom code occurrences in your project that are no longer valid in Kentico 10. The information will help you update your custom code after you perform the upgrade.**

Source - [Kentico documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/installation/upgrading-to-kentico-10/upgrading-custom-code) The documentation has all the commands to run and detect the incompatible code. This might help you.

Kentico 9 to 10 Upgrade tool - http://download.kentico.com/CMSUpgrades/Upgrade/Upgrade_9_0_10_0.exe

Basic steps to ensure before you perform upgrade - https://docs.kentico.com/k10/installation/upgrading-to-kentico-10